# Selenium element not interactable error with no feedback

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm doing some tests with Selenium Webdriver 3 and sometimes I get some errors in the Eclipse console and it says ***element not interactable*** but I can't figure out which element or at which line it occurs. How could I make this give me some useful feedback?

Already tried adding breakpoints, reading carefully the error log, just about everything I could. In this case I know at which line the code breaks but I don`t get this feedback. And the weird thing is sometimes I DO get which element breaks at which line.

Comment: The error should come with a stack trace that will tell you which file, method, and line the exception was thrown on. You should spend some time reading some tutorials on debugging, especially ones focused on Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many solutions

1. Read the error message closely
2. Add breakpoints and run in debug mode
3. Add `System.out.println("message")` at different steps
4. Pay close attention to the UI to see where script is failing
5. Breakdown the code and run it in little chunks